# How long can a flag remain active?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I have flagged the following question as a duplicate.

[SQL Parameter with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513441/sql-parameter-with-multiple-values)

Now I want to know: after how long time will it be stated as *active*?

I do not have problem with anything here. I just want to know after how long time the request (of a duplicate question) will automatically be rejected or approved.

OK, I got the things, so it will remain active until moderators will have a look at it... 
But don't you think we should have a limit that after a certain number of days this kind of request will be dropped (or cancelled)?

Comment: It will remain active until a moderator will dismiss it, or some action happens that will cause the flag to be dismissed (say the question gets closed or deleted).

Comment: If it's flagged as duplicate it can get handled by the community rather than a moderator.

Comment: so it must be done manually no automatic status change ??

Comment: Normally yes. You can track the review of your specific flag via: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2820376

Comment: @Flexo is it possible to locate a specific flag in the close vote queue?  I have one that is almost 3 months old and I'm curious about its status.

Comment: @psu I think that's a mod only thing, not sure if that's by design or a planned feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will remain active until it gets reviewed. Someone voting to close it as a duplicate via review, or the question be closed in general will dismiss it as helpful. Three people opting to leave it open via review will dismiss it as declined. The Close Votes review queue is rather large, so it could take some time. Note that moderators do not see recommend closure flags - they only go to the review queue.

Comment: Also note there is no reason at all to be concerned about having an "active" flag. It does not harm or limit you in any way while still active. Well, spam/offensive flags are kinda limiting you while active, since they "recycle", but that's not what you have here, and those always go quickly.

Comment: Loved the "rather large" when it's actually... gigantic.